# Find the domain and range of $f(x)=\sqrt{(16-x^2)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I came up with a wrong solution, can someone tell me where I went wrong?

[image: 1st page]

[image: 2nd page]

Comment: Please learn [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553) as soon as possible and edit your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sqrt{x}$ is the principal square root function, it takes nonnegative value.

Hence $y \ge 0$.

I don't see how you get $16-y^2 \ge 16$.

We have $$-4 \le x \le 4$$
$$0 \le x^2 \le 16$$

$$16-16 \le 16-x^2 \le 16-0$$

$$0 \le \sqrt{16-x^2} \le 4$$

Let $y \in [0,4]$, we let $x=\sqrt{16-y^2}$, we can check that $\sqrt{16-x^2}=\sqrt{16-(16-y^2)}=y.$

Answer (score 3):

Your domain part is correct

Now $-4 \le x \le 4$

Then $0 \le x^2\le 16$

$\Rightarrow -16\le -x^2\le 0$

$\Rightarrow 0\le 16-x^2\le 16$

$\Rightarrow 0\le \sqrt{16-x^2}\le 4$

Hence Range is $[0,4]$

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=\sqrt{16-x^2}$$note that $$\sqrt{something}\to something \geq0$$so
$$16-x^2\geq 0\\-x^2\geq -16\\ \text{multiplying by minus change the sign}\\x^2\leq 16 \\|x|\leq 4\\x\in[-4,4]$$ now try for the range
$$y=\sqrt{16-x^2}$$ note again $\sqrt{something}$ to the power of two $$y^2=16-x^2\to x^2+y^2=16$$ it is a circle in center of (0,0) ,radius=4
it seems that $$y \in[-4,4] ,\text{but remember that } \sqrt{something}\geq 0 \\so \\y \in [0,4]$$

Answer (score 1):

$y=\sqrt{16-x^2}>0\Rightarrow x\in[-4,+4]$ is a semicircle of radius $4$ since $y^2=16-x^2\Rightarrow x^2+y^2=4^2$ is a circle of radius $4$, and $y>0$. Therefore, $y\in[0,4]$.